# mysql sum() return double value using multiple joins

Tags: mysql, sql

```
select 
a.ClientID,
f.Currency,
a.OrganizationName,
COALESCE(sum(b.GrandTotal),0) as SaleGrandTotal,
COALESCE(sum(g.AmountReceived),0) as AmountReceived,
COALESCE(sum(b.GrandTotal - g.AmountReceived),0) as SaleBalanceRemaining, 
COALESCE(sum(d.GrandTotal), 0) as PurchaseGrandTotal, 
COALESCE(sum(e.AmountPaid), 0) as AmountPaid,
COALESCE(sum(d.GrandTotal - e.AmountPaid),0) as PurchaseBalanceRemaining,
COALESCE(sum(b.GrandTotal - g.AmountReceived),0) - COALESCE(sum(d.GrandTotal - e.AmountPaid),0) as Total 
from na_clients as a
join na_currency as f 

left join na_transaction as b
on a.ClientID = b.ClientID and b.CurrencyID = f.CurrencyID and b.IsActive = 1

left join na_recoverylogs as g
on b.TID = g.TID

left join na_purchase as d 
on a.ClientID = d.ClientID and d.CurrencyID = f.CurrencyID  and d.IsActive = 1

left join na_purchaselogs as e
on e.PID = d.PID

group by a.OrganizationName,f.Currency
order by a.OrganizationName
```

I am using multiple currency like dollar,CNY,rupees.
It was working fine but today i noticed sum() double value like b.GrandTotal should be 11500 but its return 23000

```
Table Client:
clientid,name,organizationName
1,client1,OrgName
2,client2,OrgName

Table Currency:
currencyid,cname
1,Dollar
2,Rupees

Table Transaction:
tid,clientid,currencyid,grandTotal,amountReceived,balanceremaining
1,1,1,11000,0,11000
2,1,1,500,0,500

Table recoveryLogs: // Another Error Here
id,tid,amountreceived
1,1,0
2,2,0
3,2,2000     // Again sum() multiply value - because of PID 2 is repeating


Table Purchase:
pid,clientid,currencyid,grandTotal,amountPaid,balanceRemaining
1,1,1,25000,0,25000
1,2,2,2,3000,1000,2000
Now I am using sum(b.grandTotal) instead of 11500 it return 23000

Table PurchaseLogs: // Another Error Here
id,pid,amountpaid
1,1,0
2,2,1000
3,1,1000            // Again sum() multiply value - because of PID 1 is repeating
```

So result should be:

```
Client: Client1
SaleGrandTotal: 11500
AmountReceived: 0
SaleBalanceRemaining: 11500
PurchaseGrandTotal: 25000
AmountPaid: 0
PurchaseBalanceRemaining: 25000
Total Amount: -13500
```

But result i get:

```
    Client: Client1
    SaleGrandTotal: 23000
    AmountReceived: 0
    SaleBalanceRemaining: 23000
    PurchaseGrandTotal: 50000
    AmountPaid: 0
    PurchaseBalanceRemaining: 50000
    Total Amount: -27000
```

If i remove purchase clause(d and e) or transaction(b and g) clause from query it's working fine individually.

Comment: any reason you're not grouping with the client id as well?

Comment: I just using ClientID for reference in view page @WilliamBurnham

Comment: In every other RDMS, this aggregate SQL query will fail as you include a non-aggregate column, `ClientID`, but do not specify it in `GROUP BY` clause. MySQL runs under several [modes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html), one of which is `ONLY FULL GROUP BY` (only as of MySQL 5.7.5 is this the default).

Comment: simply do NOT use the MySQL "extension" to group by. Always include ALL non-aggregating columns in the group by clause - and you will avoid bugs. What MySQL does when you exclude columns from the group by clause in "non-determinant" (i.e. your guess is as good as mine) in effect it arbitrarily chooses some value for the non-aggregating columns not specified in the group by clause.

Comment: Are you really using Microsoft's SQL Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason data is doubling is your `ClientID` has different occurrences in Transaction and Purchase tables and hence not a 1-to-1 match. `ClientID = 1` and `CurrencyID = 1` appears twice in Transaction and only once in Purchase. When you join the tables, a combination set of 1 x 2 = 2 `ClientID` records result with some fields repeating data. Thus, summing will double for repeat entries. As illustration:

```
      Transaction Data    | Purchase Data
row1: 1,1,1,11000,0,11000 | 1,1,1,25000,0,25000 
row2: 2,1,1,500,0,500     | 1,1,1,25000,0,25000
```

Consider separating the aggregation between both tables using derived tables. Then, join the four underlying aggregates (*transaction, purchase, recovery log, purchase log*) for final query. The join will match 1-to-1 if you aggregate, grouping on `ClientID` and `CurrencyID`, `TID` and `PID`.

```
SELECT
  transAgg.ClientID, transAgg.Currency, transAgg.OrganizationName,
  transAgg.SaleGrandTotal, recovLogAgg.SumOfAmtReceived, 
  (transAgg.SaleGrandTotal - recovLogAgg.SumOfAmtReceived) as SaleBalanceRemaining, 
  purchAgg.PurchaseGrandTotal, purchLogAgg.SumOfAmtPaid, 
  (purchAgg.PurchaseGrandTotal - purchLogAgg.SumOfAmtPaid) as PurchaseBalanceRemaining,
  ((transAgg.SaleGrandTotal - recovLogAgg.SumOfAmtReceived) - 
   (purchAgg.PurchaseGrandTotal - purchLogAgg.SumOfAmtPaid)) As [Total]

FROM
  (SELECT
      a.ClientID, f.CurrencyID, f.Currency, a.OrganizationName,
      COALESCE(sum(b.GrandTotal),0) as SaleGrandTotal
  FROM na_clients as a
  INNER JOIN na_currency as f     
  LEFT JOIN na_transaction as b
       ON a.ClientID = b.ClientID 
       AND b.CurrencyID = f.CurrencyID 
       AND b.IsActive = 1              
  GROUP BY a.ClientID, a.OrganizationName, f.CurrencyID, f.Currency
  ORDER BY a.OrganizationName) As transAgg    

INNER JOIN

  (SELECT
      a.ClientID, f.CurrencyID, f.Currency, a.OrganizationName,
      COALESCE(sum(d.GrandTotal), 0) as PurchaseGrandTotal
  FROM na_clients as a
  INNER JOIN na_currency as f     
  LEFT JOIN na_purchase as d 
       ON a.ClientID = d.ClientID 
       AND d.CurrencyID = f.CurrencyID  
       AND d.IsActive = 1          
  GROUP BY a.ClientID, a.OrganizationName, f.CurrencyID, f.Currency
  ORDER BY a.OrganizationName) As purchAgg  

ON transAgg.ClientID = purchAgg.ClientID 
AND transAgg.CurrencyID = purchAgg.CurrencyID

INNER JOIN

 (SELECT
      g.TID, COALESCE(sum(g.AmountReceived),0) As SumOfAmtReceived
  FROM na_recoverylogs as g          
  GROUP BY g.TID) As recovlogAgg  

ON transAgg.TID = recovlogAgg.TID

INNER JOIN

 (SELECT
      e.PID, COALESCE(sum(e.AmountPaid),0) As SumOfAmtPaid
  FROM na_purchaselogs as e 
  GROUP BY e.PID) As purchlogAgg

ON purchAgg.PID = purchlogAgg.PID
```

Comment: Result: http://prntscr.com/a3awaq  - It returns wrong result, there is no entry for Currency Dollar, It return multiple rows like: Pak Rupees, PakRupees, Dollar, Dollar. Above query return double result instead of 2 currency its return 4 - 2 for transAgg and 2 for purchAgg. @Parfait

Comment: See update with `CurrencyID` added to `JOIN` of derived tables.

Comment: Thanks Alot @Parfait for answer and explanation :)

Comment: again sum() return double value. I just added entry in purchaseLogs and recoveryLogs. I have updated question. Please have a look. @Parfait

Comment: You will have to separate logs (remove their current left joins) and aggregate them on their own into two more derived tables, this time joined to corresponding transAgg and purchAgg derived tables.

Comment: I tried to separate TransLogs but failed.can you please update your answer? @Parfait

Comment: See update. Notice the changed calculations in outer query, two added derived tables, and removal of log tables join in `transAgg` and `purchAgg`.